# How do I decide whether or not two bodies should collide in box2d?

Tags: box2d, libgdx

So far I've got a bunch of boxes that are my enemy prototypes moving around on a static ground body.

I don't want them to bump into each other and knock each other around, but I do want them to have collision with the ground and with any projectiles I launch.

How should I do this?

From what I've found so far, setting them as sensors seems to be the only possibility, but how do I have them not fall through the ground, and detect projectile collisions? It doesn't seem like quickly switching isSensor would work.

Is there a different/better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read this [box2d Collision Filtering](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-filtering)

you can set the catagory of bodies and then decide which bodies should collide by using maskbits.

You can also use groupIndex in this case . set groupindex of enemy bodies negative and groupIndex. For more information on this , read the above link and your concepts will be more clear.

Comment: I suggest a custom CollisionFilter... categories, groups and this stuff is confusing and not even close as powerful as a filter.

Comment: This seems like exactly what I need, thanks a bunch. Oh, and for anyone else using libgdx who wants a more java oriented tutorial for this, http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/2011/07/box2d-tutorial-collision-filtering/

Comment: @noone Alright, thanks, I'll pay attention to the filter mask stuff.

Comment: The website for the tutorial suggested in the post has a large number of great articles for Box2d.  I often end up there looking for and finding answers.